# Can I view the event loop of a browser to learn the order of JS scheduled for execution?

Tags: javascript, events, browser

I've inherited a codebase where the order in which JS executes is not clear since there's a lot of `setTimeout` calls, globals, and broken Promise chains. Rather than manually trace every execution path I'd like to capture what JS gets scheduled for execution on the browser's message queue over a time period, or in response to an event.

**I can see Event Listeners and trace from when one fires, but this is proving too slow in my case.** A single click can sprawl out into several scheduled scripts that each mutate a shared state. This is why I am not considering tracing from event handlers and am instead looking for an overarching timeline for all JS in the application.

Given that JS scripts are [scheduled for execution](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/EventLoop), how I can see the order in which JS gets queued?

I've started with something like this, but this doesn't give me a fully reliable timeline.

```
const {
  setTimeout,
  setInterval,
} = window;

window._jsq = [];

window._record = f => {
  window._jsq.push([f, new Error().stack]);
};

window.setTimeout = (...a) => {
  window._record(a[0]);
  return setTimeout.apply(window, a);
};

window.setInterval = (...a) => {
  window._record(a[0]);
  return setInterval.apply(window, a);
};
```

Comment: I would say that this would help trace performance aspects and the time that event callbacks remain queued, even if there is less chaos or complexity in one's application

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a crack at my own question from the angle of the OP snippet. Corrections appreciated.

Assuming you cannot see the message queue (or at least the scripts queued), you can still see the code that is *scheduling* other JS and the code that is *scheduled* to run. So, tracking both independently is possible.

This is not all good news because you still have to do legwork to 1) adapt that tracking to the various ways JS can get scheduled, and 2) make sense of what you capture.

In the `setTimeout` case, something quick and dirty like this can at least provide a sense of a scheduling timeline and when things actually happened. That's just a matter of wrapping functions.

```
const { setTimeout } = window;

// For visibility in DevTools console
window._schedulers = [];
window._calls = [];

const wrap = f => {
  const { stack } = new Error();

  window._schedulers.push([stack, f]);

  return (...a) => {
    window._calls.push([stack, f, a]);

    return f(...a);
  };
};

window.setTimeout = (f, delay, ...a) => {
  return setTimeout.apply(window, [wrap(f), delay].concat(a));
}
```

Still, that's just one case and says nothing about when to start/stop monitoring and the potential trigger points where traceability is a concern as Mosè Raguzzini mentioned. In the case of Promises, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25831216/394397) calls out Bluebird's checking facilities.

It seems that until more native tools come out that visualize queued scripts and related info, you are stuck collecting and analyzing the data by hand.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in automatic debugging tool for monitoring your browser event loop.
In order to monitor the browser's event loop you have to explicity monitor the event that are in your interested in and pass it to the (in this case Chrome's) DevTool:

```
monitorEvents(document.body, "click");
```

[More info about monitoring events in Chrome Dev Tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events)

**Note #1:** You don't know how custom events are called. They may not dispatch an event into the DOM (e.g. some libraries implement their own event registration and handling systems) so there is no general way of knowing when event listeners are being called, even if you can track the dispatch of the event.

Some libraries also simulate event bubbling, but again, unless you know the type of event, you can't listen for it.

However, you could implement your own event management system and implement a function to listen for all events for which listeners are set or events dispatched using your system.

Ref: [How can I monitor all custom events emitted in the browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5984551/how-can-i-monitor-all-custom-events-emitted-in-the-browser)

**Note #2:** a modern JS approach to events (IE: React/Redux) involves dispatching ACTIONS instead of events. As actions are often `logged` for `time-travel` purpose, monitoring events in this case is unnecessary.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way, but this is a real bummer. JS browser apps are at a point where tracing goes far beyond events so I'm surprised this kind of problem hasn't seen more attention. I'll let this thread play out a bit more to see if there are any other ideas.

Comment: Thanks for the edits! Even with event and action tracing I would like to trace JS scheduled for execution by forms like `(() => { setTimeout(f) asyncFunc() })()`. The nice thing about that kind of tracking is that it should be implementation-agnostic for the app.

Comment: In react/redux also a *form submit* is a ACTION dispatch and not an event dispatch. The real problem is described in note 1, as libraries often implements function listener and wrappers with custom bubbling