# Can I listen to all events emitted by a javascript target?

Tags: javascript

`addEventListener` lets me add one listener to a target associated with some event type.

Can I somehow listen to all the events emitted by a target? Every time a specified object emits an event - any event - I want to log the type of the event.

Comment: Related: [How do you log all events fired by an element in jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439570/how-do-you-log-all-events-fired-by-an-element-in-jquery)

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to programmatically catch all events on the page in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107232/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-catch-all-events-on-the-page-in-the-browser)

Comment: I don't think there is any "generic" event to  handle all the others, but maybe you can search for an object which lists all the possible events ? I don't know if there is a way to read the [GlobalEventHandlers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers) interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery you could bind all the standard JavaScript events using:

```
$('#element').bind('blur focus focusin focusout load resize scroll unload click dblclick mousedown mouseup  mousemove mouseover mouseout mouseenter mouseleave change select submit keydown keypress keyup error', function(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
}
```