# addEventListener with Regular Expression

Tags: javascript, regex, dom-events, addeventlistener

Is it possible to add `eventListener` with regex?

Something like this:

```
document.addEventListener(""+/\d+/+"", function (data) {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: Can you explain your purpose more?

Comment: Sure. I want to send event.initEvent("someNumber") from the page and listen to that event on content script for chrome extension. I have "someNumber" only as string in window variable

Comment: If you have delimited event names, you can put them into the addEventListener.

Comment: How about `if(regex.test(eventName)) { ... document.addEventListener(eventName, ... ) ... }` ?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible to attach an event listener to events by mask. You can take a list of events, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5107232/is-it-possible-to-programmatically-catch-all-events-on-the-page-in-the-browser), for example and listen to all of them in a cycle to attach our handler to them.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't understand why in http://krasimirtsonev.com/blog/article/Send-message-from-web-page-to-chrome-extensions-background-script you can listen to "hello" and you can't use regex?

Comment: @Dusty This is an interface for Chrome extensions: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime